# How to access JSON property values in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I'm creating a view in an `Ember.js App` and want to display some values from a `JSON object`. In my route's model hook, I'm calling an `API endpoint` that returns the `JSON object` which contains two `arrays`.

I thought I'd be able to simply reference the `JSON properties` in my `handlebars template` and it'd output the value, but that isn't working as expected. Instead, it looks like I'm getting a string description of the JSON object:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can I access the `JSON object's property values` in my handlebars template?

route:

```
var CompareRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return $.getJSON('/api/compare_segments?' + params.ids).then(function(payload) {
      return payload;
    });
  },

});

export default CompareRoute;
```

Handlebars template:

```
{{item_summaries}}
```

Example of `JSON` formatted returned from `API endpoint` (truncated):

```
{
  "item_summaries": [
    {
      "item_desc": "example",
      "item_id": 1,
      "item_summary": [
        {
          "children": [
                {
                  "measure": "% users clicking",
                  "value": null
                }
    ...

    {
      "item_desc": "example2",
      "item_id": 2,
      "item_summary": [
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the each helper because you have a collection which needs to be printed out.

```
{{#each item_summaries}}
  //access the properties of a single item_summary and write your html code
{{/each}}
```